# How can I copy index in Elastic Search with this architecture?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a scenario where I have to import data (millions of records) from multiple sources and save it in a database. A user should get results in under 2-3 seconds when they try to search for any information related to that data.

For this, I designed an architecture where I used golang to import data from multiple sources and pushed data in AWS SQS. I've created a lambda function which triggers when AWS SQS has some data. This lambda function then pushes data in AWS Elastic Search. I've created a Rest API using which I give results to the user.

I use CRON to do this importing work every morning. Now my problem is if a new batch of data comes I want to delete the existing data and replace all of them with the new data.
I'm stuck at how I can achieve this deleting and adding new data part.

I thought of creating a temporary index and then replacing it with the original index. But the problem is I do not know when importing has ended and can make this index switch.

Comment: the CRON job which starts the process every morning could call a single script which creates a temporary index, starts the download from different sources and then makes this original index point to new index created when all the download processes have returned and deletes the original index or archives it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept you're after is an [index alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html). The basic workflow would be:

1. Import today's data into an index with `my-index-2019-09-16` (for example).
2. Make sure the import is complete and worked correctly.
3. Point the alias to the new index (it's an atomic switch between the indices):

   ```
   POST /_aliases
   {
       "actions" : [
           { "remove" : { "index" : "my-index-2019-09-15", "alias" : "my-index" } },
           { "add" : { "index" : "my-index-2019-09-16", "alias" : "my-index" } }
       ]
   }
   ```
4. Delete the old index.

You will double the disk space during the import process, but otherwise this should work without any issues and you only delete data once it has a proper replacement.